# Netsuite Customer Statement (PDF/HTML)

Tags: pdf, if-statement, freemarker, netsuite

I had a need to display the `amount.paid` on invoices (line items) on the customer statement.

Below is the solution I came up with, after i was suggested to include the `toNumber function`

Comment: the first line; how to show the `amount.paid` on invoices (line items) on customer statements @NineBerry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that information, I was able to come up with a statement table that gives me what I wanted.

- Each line will display a charge, if it is an invoice
- Will show the amount paid, if it is an invoice with payments applied
- If it is a payment/deposit/credit, the payment column will show the total paid on that payment.
- The balance column will display an amount if, it as unpaid or partially paid invoice
- and the running column, will display the running total of the statement
- **(see below for code)**

  ```
  <table>
      <#list statement.lines as line>
  <#if line_index==0>

  <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Description</th>
   <th>References #</th>
   <th>Charge</th>
   <th>Payment</th>
   <th>Balance Due</th>
   <th>Running</th>
  </tr>
  </thead>

  </#if>
   <tr>
   <#function toNumber val><#if val?has_content && val?length gt 0 ><#return val?html?replace('[^0-9.]','','r')?number ><#else><#return 0 ></#if></#function>
   <#assign amountpaid=(line.charge?int-line.amountremaining?int)>
    <td>${line.datecol}</td>
    <td>${line.description}</td>
    <td>${line.otherrefnum}&nbsp;-&nbsp;${line.custbodyjobnum}</td>
    <td>${line.charge}</td>
    <td><#if amountpaid gt 0>${amountpaid?string.currency}<#else>${line.payment}</#if></td>
    <td>${line.amountremaining}</td>
    <td>${line.balance}</td>
  </tr>
  </#list>
  </table>
  ```